# C# protobuf without attributes

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Hi how i can use protobuf without attributes? because i need change binary serialization to protobuf. How i can use RuntypeModel for this?

```
 var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly();
var types = assembly.GetTypes();
foreach (var t in types.Where(x => x.Namespace.Contains("PlainEntities")))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", t.FullName);
    var meta = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(t, false);
    var index = 1;

    // FIND ANY DERIVED CLASS FOR THE ENTITY
    foreach (var d in types.Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(t)))
    {
        var i = index++;
        Console.WriteLine("\tSubtype: {0} - #{1}", d.Name, i);
        meta.AddSubType(i, d);
    }

    // THEN ADD THE PROPERTIES
    foreach (var p in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Where(x => x.GetSetMethod() != null))
    {
        var i = index++;
        Console.WriteLine("\tProperty: {0} - #{1}", p.Name, i);
        meta.AddField(i, p.Name);
    }
}
```

and where in project it's must be?

Thanks

Comment: How add this attributes for all assemblies in project?

Comment: Why do you want to use protobuf over binary serialization? what you want to do seems like it will nullify all benefits protobuf gives over binary serialization and adding a lot of complications and likely badly performing reflection code

Comment: because protobuf is faster - and i have big projects and i can't add attributes in all classes